# how to increment and decrement a value with SESSION in php after submit

Tags: php, ajax, session, increment

In a form, i have 2 submit buttons:

```
<td><input class="surveysubmit" type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous"/></td>
<td><input class="surveysubmit" type="submit" name="next" value="Next"/></td>
```

When i click on the `previous`, it should decrement the SESSION with `-1`
When hit the `next`, it should increment the SESSION with `+ 1`

(I use ajax for sending data to php)

The php code:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 


    if(!isset($_SESSION['i']))  {
        $_SESSION['i'] = 0;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['previous'])){
        $_SESSION['i']--;
    }
    if(isset($_POST['next'])){
        $_SESSION['i']++;
    }
    echo $_SESSION['i'];
```

What happens: the first and second time i submit with `next`, it increments with +1. After another submit, it increments with +2. 
What i am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

This is my js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.surveysubmit', function() {

        var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
        formData.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });

        $.ajax({        
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '',
            data : formData,
            success :   function(data) {    

                            $("#question").fadeOut(500).hide(function() {
                                $(".surveywrapper").fadeIn(500).show(function() {
                                    $(".surveywrapper").html(data);                                 
                                });                                                             
                            });

                        }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why that would happen. Check your log, make sure you're not submitting twice.

Comment: The problem could be in your JavaScript code that sends the AJAX requests, maybe it's sending twice.

Comment: @Barmar; i agree. Without ajax, it works fine. But what is wrong with the js?

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause multiple submits. Are you sure you're not adding the event handler multiple times?

Comment: Add a `console.log()` statement to it, to see if it's running multiple times.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe it's the type of input used. Maybe they should use a `<button>` and a submit type instead of `<input>`.

Comment: I don't think that matters.

Comment: Well, if there's a form with a POST method that we don't see and they're using ajax with inputs like that, I think that would submit twice.

Comment: Open the console if you have Chrome press f12.
Look at the network requests tab.

Comment: You are right: in the console log (network) he fires twice

Comment: removing type="submit" doesn't make sense. It keeps firing twice and it does not incrment with =1 anymore

Comment: add console.log (1) to js code and check console contents

Comment: remove $ (". surveywrapper"). html (data); this inserts duplicate js code